# Creating stacked bar charts from CSV file in R with multiple categories on x-axis

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, graph

I have a CSV file with something like that:

```
"partyname", "category1", "category2"
"FirstName", "2.0", "8.0"
"SecondName", "3.0", "9.0" 
"ThirdName", "4.0", "20.0"
```

With many more data point.

I want to create a stacked bar chart with `partyname` being the fill color in the chart, on the y-axis I want a percentage scale, and on the x-axis (this is where I struggle), I want to have all the categories (`category1`, etc.) being different labels (like if they were years going from 2010 to 2020).

All I have been able to do now is summing the categories together and creating on the x-axis that one category “summed up” which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get the data in long format for all the category values. Calculate the percentage value for each `category` and then plot a stacked bar chart.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('category'), names_to = "category") %>%
  mutate(value = round(prop.table(value) * 100, 2), .by = category) %>%
  ggplot(aes(category, value, fill = partyname)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(value, '%')),position = position_stack(vjust = .5))
```

[image]

Comment: I’m a newbie with R… Would you mind explaining step by step what it means? Notably, I don’t understand what the "long format" means, and how you determine in the code that from column 2, it is the category that needs to be on the x-axis.

Comment: Also, the numbers in the csv table are already percentages. So I don’t need to make them percentages, and I don’t want a percent stacked barchart, just a simple stacked barchart that does not make up 100%. If you detail the steps of the code in your answer, I think I would be able to figure this out, so it would really help.

Comment: Long format (also known as tidy format) data is when every row contains only one observation. Here's a link where you can read more about it https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html . To know what happens at each step I would suggest to run the code line by line and see how the output changes. Moreover, if you don't want to calculate the percentage then remove this `mutate(value = round(prop.table(value) * 100, 2), .by = category) %>%` line from the code.